# for what purpose we use time module in scraping with BeautifulSoup libraries python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web

*I've been facing an issue where the code I'm working with is functioning properly on some websites, but not on others. I'm not sure why this is happening, and I'm seeking help from anyone who may have experience with similar issues or expertise in the specific programming languages and systems involved. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/property/uk/'


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get(url)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

html_content = driver.page_source

driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

property_cards = soup.find_all('li', class_='otm-PropertyCard isOwu')

for property in property_cards:
    title = property.find('span', class_="title")
    location = property.find('span', class_="address")
    price = property.find('div', class_="otm-Price")
    Extrainfo = property.find('li', class_="otm-ListItemOtmBullet before:bg-brand-contrast")
    #more = property.find('div', class_="otm-PropertyCardInfo")
    
    print(f'title: {title.text}')
    print(f'location: {location.text}')
    print(f'price: {price.text}')
    print(f'Extrainfo: {Extrainfo.text}')
    #print(f'more: {more.text}')
    print()
```

Comment: Could you please focus your question - the title mentions the `time module` but it does not appear in the content and what is the exact problem *facing an issue*? Please take the [tour] and read [ask] Thanks

Comment: Try replacing `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` with `time.sleep(10)` don't forget to `import time`

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: weird bugs can happen with loading elements, so its easier to wait

Waiting can be a pretty standard thing when scraping the web, because not all of elements may be loaded yet. Trying to access these elements before they are load can cause a bunch of weird hard to find intermittent bugs. Usually images and external loading.